# Link which explains how to format a letter to Nature

Tags: publications, writing, formatting

I need to write a letter to Nature and a friend of mine said that Nature wants the Author to follow a very precise format.

He said that the explanation of the structure of the format is an example of a letter in which: there were different colours for the different sections, it also explained what to write in each section and which words use/don't use etc

Does anybody know the link where I can find such information?

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. Do you want to submit a paper to the journal? Or just write a letter and ask them something?!

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: *Nature* has a section for "letters" which are really very short papers, or at least research announcements.  I assume that's what's meant here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Such information is invariably posted on a journal's website, and *Nature* is no exception. Go to [Nature's current issue website](http://www.nature.com/nature/current_issue.html), click "[For Authors](http://www.nature.com/nature/authors/index.html)" and "[Manuscript Formatting Guide](http://www.nature.com/nature/authors/gta/index.html)". Under "[Letters](http://www.nature.com/nature/authors/gta/index.html#a1.2)" there is an "[annotated example](http://www.nature.com/nature/authors/gta/2c_Summary_para.pdf)" which looks like what you are describing.

Comment: It looks to me like the colorization isn't required. It's just there to illuminate the required sections in the summary paragraph.

Comment: Yes, it's true!